# tkinter Entry to StringVar() binding do not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

i have a issue, that i did not figured out why..
All needed code is summarized in this screenshot:
[Screenshot_Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJarO.png)

Please do not look for sense, i trimmed the code as far as possible, to show the problem only.

My Issue as is follows:

- If i run main.py
- Then click Button according to "ui_root.py"
- and then input some text in the Entry-Field and click Button according to "create_user.py"
- Then my print Statement is empty, respectivly the StringVar() binding do not work

Bu if i run "create_user.py" directly (**uncomment UiCreateUser()**) then my print-Statement prints exactly the content/text from my Entry-Widget.

Why? I dont get it, i would apprciate it if someone can help me out.. thanks in advance.

The code for copy and paste purpose(for read use screenshot, it may be better than this):

**main.py**

```
from ui_root import UiRoot
app = UiRoot()
app.mainloop()
```

**ui_root.py**

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button
from pixela_brain import PixelaBrain

class UiRoot(Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.brain = PixelaBrain()

        self.button = Button(self, text="Button", command=self.click)
        self.button.pack()

    def click(self):
        self.brain.create_user()
```

**pixela_brain.py**

```
from popup_windows import create_user
import json


class PixelaBrain:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def create_user(self):
        self.new_user = create_user.UiCreateUser()
```

**create_user.py**

```
from tkinter import Tk, Entry, Button, StringVar


class UiCreateUser(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Entry
        self.entry_var = StringVar()
        self.entry = Entry(self, textvariable=self.entry_var)
        self.entry.pack()

        # Button
        self.button = Button(self, text="Click", command=self.btn_click)
        self.button.pack()

        self.mainloop()

    def btn_click(self):
        print(self.entry_var.get())


# UiCreateUser()
```

Comment: You are creating multiple instances of (subclasses of) `Tk`.  Each is an entirely separate environment, with its own Vars, images, etc. that are not accessible from any other instance.  You need to use `Toplevel()` instead to create additional windows.

Comment: But i create the StringVar() in the class UiCreateUser and i am accessing it in the same class (object, instance,...). So i do not try to acess StringVar() from another instance. I am confused :)

Comment: You aren't explicitly creating the `StringVar` in any particular `Tk` instance, so one gets chosen for you (I think it's the first one that was ever created in the program).  The class containing the code has absolutely nothing to do with it.

Comment: Try changing `self.entry_var = StringVar()` to `self.entry_var = StringVar(master=self)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This as an "answer" because the input from jasonharper (in the comments above) solved my problem and i want to close the question.

Just replacing **class UiCreateUser(Tk)** with **class UiCreateUser(Toplevel)** solved the problem.

Many thanks :)